# How to mock DOM methods in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

How to mock following code snippet in **Jest** :

```
useEffect(() => {
        document
            .getElementById('firstname')
            ?.querySelector('input-field')
            ?.setAttribute('type', 'password')
    }, [])
```

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

post your use effect code incase you forgot to add empty array dependancy inside useEffect so that time useEffect code re reRender every time when state change E.g

useEffect(() => {

},[])

//inside your code only call one time when component first time rendered

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am expecting, API should be call ones in application lifecycle, even if i switch to different screen. You are telling about rendering api one time using empty dependency in single component lifecycle. I am looking for whole component lifecycle.

Comment: then  use Redux state when first time api call that time update your redux state key  and call your API code  depend on redux state key